# When attempting to update mediawiki, I get the following error. How can I resolve this?

Tags: server, 18.04, php, mediawiki

So when I try to run the update script, I get this message:

`A copy of your installation's LocalSettings.php                                                                                                                                                                      must exist and be readable in the source directory.                                                                                                                                                                  Use --conf to specify it.`

The command I execute is: `php maintenance/update.php`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify to the maintenance script the path of the LocalSettings.php file. For example:

```
php maintenance/importImages.php --conf /var/wwwdata/website.org/wiki/LocalSettings.php /tmp/wikiimages .jpg .png .svg
```

[Source](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Maintenance_scripts)